# value returned by beautifulsoup is different from the value in html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The value returned by BeautifulSoup is different from the value displayed on the HTML code:

```
<div class="fieldYear">2013</div>
<div class="fieldMileage">132 000 km</div>
```

If I apply beautifulsoup like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL_accueil = "https://www.lacentrale.fr/listing?mileageMax=150000&priceMax=17000&priceMin=5000&yearMin=2012&age=1"
page_accueil = requests.get(URL_accueil)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_accueil.content, "lxml").find('div', {"class": "resultListContainer"})
print(soup)
```

I will get :

2012 

146Â 520Â km

Why does BeautifulSoup return the wrong values? I don't have 2013 for year and 132000km.

I tried to add

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_accueil.content, "lxml", from_encoding='utf-8')
```

but I also get different values from the values displayed.

Comment: no in html code there is not "146Â 520Â km"  and even if there is something like that, why if I apply this code (which is related to the good chunk in html) :
    km = str(a.find('div', {"class": "fieldMileage"}).text.strip('km'))
I also get the wrong value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the source code, the spaces are probably encoded with Unicode char [00A0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) (non breakable space). Depending on the browser you use to read the source code, you may see a simple space character (edge, firefox) or a HTML equivalent `&nbsp;` (chrome, opera). This is only a trick used by some browser to help you "visualize" the specific char code for space.

**Edit:** To fix the issue, simply initialise your BeautifulSoup object with `page_accueil.text` instead of `page_accueil.content`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL_accueil = "https://www.lacentrale.fr/listing?mileageMax=150000&priceMax=17000&priceMin=5000&yearMin=2012&age=1"
page_accueil = requests.get(URL_accueil)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_accueil.text, "lxml")
result = soup.find('div', {"class": "fieldMileage"})

print(result.text)
```

returns

```
147 840 km
```

**Edit2:** Apparently, the returned page has a different content depending on the user agent used to perform request...

Let's try with a fake Google Chrome user agent:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
# [...]
page_accueil = requests.get(URL_accueil, headers={'User-Agent': str(UserAgent().chrome)})
```

result:

```
134 500 km
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, any tips to handle this problem please ?

Comment: Use `page_accueil.text` instead of `page_accueil.content` to initialise BS instance

Comment: ok thanks :) , but we should get 132 000 km not 147 840 km?
if you open the link the first car has 132 000 km!

Comment: Yeah, when I wrote this code, the first result was a car with 147 000 km. The remote website is dynamic, depending on the moment you execute the script, you will get a different result. I don't see any problem here

Comment: I filter by kilometeres and there is no car with 147 840 km !
also yes the website is dynamic but the first car doesn't change from this morning, it's always the same

Comment: Ok, I see the point. See my second edit. I think LaCentrale has some security code that detects you are not a normal visitor but a robot, and return a different content in such case.

Comment: yess, it's work, many thanks I never use something about useragent() I will take look on this methode, I have a lot to learn about web scraping :)